# Rewriting slow R function in C++ & Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

I have this line of R code:

```
croppedDNA <- completeDNA[,apply(completeDNA,2,function(x) any(c(FALSE,x[-length(x)]!=x[-1])))]
```

What it does is identify the sites (cols) in a matrix of DNA sequences (1 row = one seq) that are not universal (informative) and subsets them from the matrix to make a new 'cropped matrix' i.e. get rid of all the columns in which values are the same. For a big dataset this takes about 6 seconds. I don't know if I can do it faster in C++ (still a beginner in C++) but it will be good for me to try. My idea is to use Rcpp, loop through the columns of the CharacterMatrix, pull out the column (the site) as a CharacterVector check if they are the same. If they are the same, record that column number/index, continue for all columns. Then at the end make a new CharacterMatrix that only includes those columns. It is important that I keep the rownames and column names as they are in th "R version" of the matrix i.e. if a column goes, so should the colname.

I've been writing for about two minutes, so far what I have is (not finished):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterMatrix reduce_sequences(CharacterMatrix completeDNA)
{
  std::vector<bool> informativeSites; 
  for(int i = 0; i < completeDNA.ncol(); i++)
  {
    CharacterVector bpsite = completeDNA(,i);
    if(all(bpsite == bpsite[1])
    {
      informativeSites.push_back(i);
    }
  }
CharacterMatrix cutDNA = completeDNA(,informativeSites);
return cutDNA;
}
```

Am I going the right way about this? Is there an easier way. My understanding is I need std::vector because it's easy to grow them (since I don't know in advance how many cols I am going to want to keep). With the indexing will I need to +1 to the informativeSites vector at the end (because R indexes from 1 and C++ from 0)?

Thanks,
Ben W.

Comment: Good start, but you can't use negative indices in C/C++ ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Yes you can, provided whatever you're using it with starts at the middle of an array or overloads it to deal with negatives. For example, `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; int *mid = &arr[2]; int x = mid[-1]; //x = 2`

Comment: can you confirm that `class(completeDNA)` is `matrix` and not `data.frame`. `apply` is slow and there might be simple improvements to do to your R code before jumping to c++.

Comment: That is splitting hairs.  Indices go from 0 to n-1, with the indexing starting (almost always) at what corresponds to the start of the "thing" you are indexing.

Comment: Yes completeDNA is of matrix class as confirmed by 'class(completeDNA)'.

Comment: For the if line in the C++ code above a shortcut assumption can be made that if all of the vector bpsite is not equal to the first element of vector bpsite, then it is not a universally shared site, so something like if(!all(bpsite == bpsite[1]))?

Comment: To help benchmark answers, can you provide the matrix dimensions for the input and output? Also, how many distinct values for the character values?

Comment: The input matrix is of 3x398508 and the output of my test data is 3x6577. The matrix is of DNA sites and diff() does not like this, I could convert sites to 1,2,3,4 cf a,t,c,g. edit - As well as the four bases there could be N or - in the alignment so there are 6 possible distinct values.

Comment: Returning to the C++ version, I'm having compile issues at line 10, it expects something before the ',' in the line 'CharacterVector bpsite = completeDNA(,i);'. I was under the impression it was ok to subset Rcpp matrices in this way providing '()' rather than'[]' was used?

Comment: Reading around a bit more, it seems the easiest way to subset matrices is to use armadillo ( which is new to me but the example I've seen seems intuitive) or use SubMatrix. What is the most recommended solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
z <- matrix(sample(c("a", "t", "c", "g", "N", "-"), 3*398508, TRUE), 3, 398508)
```

OP's solution:

```
system.time(y1 <- z[,apply(z,2,function(x) any(c(FALSE,x[-length(x)]!=x[-1])))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.929   0.043   4.976
```

A faster version using base R:

```
system.time(y2 <- (z[, colSums(z[-1,] != z[-nrow(z), ]) > 0]))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.087   0.011   0.098
```

The results are identical:

```
identical(y1, y2)
# [1] TRUE
```

It's very possible c++ will beat it, but is it really necessary?

Comment: That's wonderful, I suppose the summing is quick because of vectorization R is strong at doing. I'll accept this as the answer to go into the code I'll use in the pipeline. I'll have a go at the c++ but really for my own education. Thanks, flodel!

Comment: (+1) for thinking *inside* the box :-)